# How to fix these proguard warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I am using a third party library in my project, since then proguard is issuing me these warnings, which I can't relate to that library, Here is the library I am using: [Lollipin](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/LolliPin).

**Warnings I am getting**

```
Warning:android.databinding.DataBindingUtil: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
Warning:android.databinding.ViewDataBinding: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
Warning:there were 43 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**What I have tried?**

I have edited `proguard-rules.pro` like this:

```
-keeppackagenames com.github.orangegangsters.lollipin
```

Still no go! I have also tried to clean and rebuild project that also didn't work out.

Here is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.teach"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 27
    versionName "5.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile ('com.github.orangegangsters:lollipin:2.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 23):

I had same issue,so I added below change into my proguard.cfg

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }

-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: first two lines is enough for me

Comment: You can add rule -ignorewarnings if you want to compile your code by ignoring warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-dontwarn com.github.orangegangsters.lollipin
```

instead of

```
-keeppackagenames com.github.orangegangsters.lollipin
```

Answer (score -4):

It's because of Lollipin using Databinding library.

Just add here to gradle:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer.