# My app crashes after proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I added the following rules in my `proguard.rules` file.
Now when I am running a debug build from android-studio, it is working but when I generate a signed apk, it crashes on Launch.

```
 #### -- Picasso --

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**


#### -- databinding --

-dontwarn android.databinding.**

#### -- Apache Commons --

-dontwarn  org.apache.http.entity.**
```

**And here are the logs**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForQaRelease'.

Job failed, see logs for details
Warning:org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.Args
Warning:org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:android.databinding.DataBindingUtil: can't find referenced class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40253929/3395198

Comment: write  `-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.* { ;}` in proguard rules

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rules below

```
# Okio
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**

#databinding
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }

 # OkHttp
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```